# How to Disable GL_DEPTH_TEST only for one Object

Tags: opengl-es

I have a question...
Is it possible to disable the GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST for only one Object?
In my example a have a Groundplane, with a Alphashadow Texture and I want to disable
the DEPTH_TEST for my Carmodel, to fake shadows. The other Objects should't have the DEPTH_TEST Disabled, so I wouldn't see the shadows through them.

Here is a Screenshot (the shadows aren't perfecty translated to their objects, but I think you will get my problem)  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18265107/special/screenshot.png

Comment: You can enable/disable the depth test whenever you want.

Comment: yes but at every moment I will see my shadows through my containers

Comment: Anything you disable depth-test for will show on top of other stuff. You can choose to do, or not do, that for anything you like. However I don't think it will fix your shadows. Why do you think you need depth-test disabled at all?

Comment: a want to disable depth-test, so the car would have a darker contrast under a shadow. But I think the only way to fake shadows is to let the dept-test enabled and the car will have same contrast

Comment: To achieve what you were wanting, disabling depth-test isn't enough, and you would need to render things in the right order. First, render the ground. Then render the car. Then render the shadows, with depth-test disabled. Then render the rest of the environment. However this assumes the ground is flat, and that shadows don't cast onto other scene objects, which will probably look wrong.

Comment: wow it works :) thank you very much. And you're right I have to position the shadow in a way, so no shadows will be casted on other objects to keep the realistic look ;)

Comment: @JasonD Actually, your comment is an answer. I propose you to post an answer too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you disable depth-test for will show on top of other stuff. You can choose to do, or not do, that for anything you like. However I don't think it will fix your shadows.

To achieve what you were wanting, disabling depth-test isn't enough, and you would need to render things in the right order:

1. render the ground.
2. render the car.
3. render the shadows, with depth-test disabled.
4. render the rest of the environment.

However this assumes the ground is flat, and that shadows don't cast onto other scene objects, which will probably look wrong.